# how to gap a list in half

Tags: css, list

I'm having a small issue with a CSS design that I can't make it work correctly.

using this example code: http://jsbin.com/EsituB/1/edit?html,css,output

I want to have the "white" list to be aligned with the "red" list, when the row is filled:

**from this**:

[image]

**into this**:

[image]

But I do not know how many "red"'s I have (they are dynamic), so I'm strugling on how to calculate the `last` "white" in each row so I can do `margin-right: 0;`

example code with `last` appended manually: http://jsbin.com/EsituB/3/edit?html,css,output

Is there a nice way to accomplish this? even using jQuery...

Comment: The last time i tryed that the only solution was to moving to another container using Javascript

Comment: @Edorka then I will have a hard time to make things ordered :(

Comment: are red cells appended throght javascript? is number of white cells fixed?

Comment: @Hiral no, none of the cells are fixed, they change everyday (it contains products available that day), but I know the `length` of each list (cell count, for both lists) if that's what you're after. `Red` cells can vary from 0 (zero) to `n`. White cells have always `>= 20`.

Comment: ok and they are appended through javascript right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add float:right; to    ul.products-2 li.last

```
ul.products-2 li.last { 
  float:right;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/EjilIdO/2

http://jsbin.com/EjilIdO/2/edit?html,css,js,output

add javascript to the function on load or in some event

```
// no of row 
var row = 2;
// no of red item
var red= $('.products-1 li').length;
console.log(red);

// first number to be marked last
var firstnumber = Math.round(red/row)*2+row*row;
// for 2 no of row
/*
    if the set is 4, first item will be 8;
    if the set is 5, first item will be 10;
    if the set is 6, first item will be 10;
    if the set is 7, first item will be 12;

*/
/* iterating each li item*/
$( ".products-2 li" ).each(function( index ) {

   // as index is started with 0, increment index by 1 and check 
   // whether it match with firstnumber
   // if match, then append last and increment the firstnumber by row*row
   // if not match, remove last 
   if(index+1==firstnumber)
   {
           $(this).addClass('last');
           firstnumber = firstnumber + row*2;
   } 
   else
   {
           $(this).removeClass('last');
   }


});
```

Comment: my problem is "HOW" do I know where to append the `last` to! My second code has `last` appended manually, I want to do it **automatically**. You can see my second code example that I know how to do it "manually" as well.

Comment: You can check the solution by appending item in first ul